# How to calculate videos that have been viewed in the last 30 days from Google Analytics without using "LastViewedDate" matrics

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I want to calculate videos that have been viewed in last 30 days without using Google Analytics metrics "LastviewDate". Is there any way to calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have added this as a custom dimension on your own Google analytics does not have a metric called last view date or a dimension by that name.  Being that its a date it is probably a dimension and not a metric.

You should check the dimension and metric reference [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) you will find a list of all valid metadata for the Google Analytics api.

Assuming you have added this as a custom dimension you should check the custom dimension metadata [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns)